# Hidden Markov Model Emission Probability Covariance is an identity matrix?

Tags: matrix, covariance, hidden-markov-models

When using an HMM, the emission probability per state should be set. If it is not set, the covariance would be an identity matrix. This is the default covariance in most HMM libraries that I used.

What does it mean if the covariance of an emission probability is an identity matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know what packages nor the programming language you are using, I will only endeavor to guess what you mean in order to help you.

The emission probability in an HMM model  [image: eq] is simply a function from [image: eq2] . There aren't any restrictions on the [image: ep]-s and therefore we could assume these are drawing from a multivariate p.d.f. which require a Vector of means and a Variance-Covariance matrix.

Now what does it mean that we have a Variance-Covariance matrix = Identity  as default? Simply it means that our multivariate distribution for [image: ep]s   follow the means we specified and are **independent** between each other and each has a variance of 1.
Usually though, emmissions in an HMM are discrete rather than continuous, let alone multivariate! :)

Comment: In the hmm library (jahmm), the emission probability requires means and covariance matrix, not variance-covariance matrix? see constructor here http://jahmm.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/0.6.2/index.html?be/ac/ulg/montefiore/run/jahmm/OpdfMultiGaussian.html

Am I doing this right? Should I put a covariance matrix or a variance-covariance matrix?

Comment: It's the same thing! :D tge correct name is variance-covariance matrix, but ppl can name is covariance matrix